# sqlite, filter rows with dynamic number of keys, but only if they have the same value in a specific column?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am brand new to sqlite (and databases in general). I have done a ton of reading both here and elsewhere and am unable to find this specific problem. People tend to want counts, or duplicates. I need to filter.

I have a database with 3 columns (and a few hundred thousand entries)

```
column1 column2 column3
abc     123     @#$
egf     456     $%#
abc     321     !@#
kop     123     &$%    
pok     321     ^$#
```

and so on.

What I am trying to do is this. I need to retrieve all possible combinations of a list. For example

```
[123, 321]
```

all possible combos would be

```
[123],[321],[123,321]
```

I do not know what input can possibly be, it can be more than 2 strings, and so the combinations list can grow pretty fast. For single entries above, like 123, 321, it works out of the gate, the thing I am trying to get to work is with more than 1 value in a list.

So I am dynamically generating the select statement

```
sqlquery = "SELECT fileloc, frequency FROM words WHERE word=?"
    while numOfVariables < len(list):
        sqlquery += " or word=?"
        numOfVariables += 1
```

This generates the query, then I execute it with

```
cursor.execute(sqlquery,tuple(list))
```

Which works. It finds me all rows with any of those combinations.

Now I need one more thing, I need it to ONLY select them if their column1 is the same (I do not know what this value may be).

So in the above example it would select rows 1 and 3 because their column2 has the values I am interested in, and their column1 is the same. But column 4 would not be selected even though it has value we want. Because it's column1  does not match 321's column1. Same thing for row 5, again even though its one of the values we need, it's column1 doesnt match 123's.

From things Ive been able to find, people compare against specific value by using GROUP BY. But in my case I do not know what that value may be. All I care about is if its the same between the rows or not.

I am sorry if my explanation is not clear. I have never used mysql before this week so I dont know all the technical terms.

But basically I need the functionality of (pseudo code):

```
if (column2 is 123 or 321) and 123.column1 == 321.column1:
       count
   else:
       dont count
```

I have a feeling this can be done by first moving whatever matches 123 or 321 into a new table. Then going through that table and only keeping records that have both 123 and 321 with the same column1 value. But I am not sure how to do this or if its the proper approach? Because this thing is going to scale pretty quick, if there are 5 inputs, then the rows that are kept is if there is one row to account for each input and all of their column1 is the same. (So rows would be saved in sets of 5).

Thank you.

(I am using Python 2.7.15)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

- "I need to retrieve **all possible combinations** of a list"
- "Now I need one more thing, I need it to ONLY select them if their **column1 is the same** (I do not know what this value may be).

Use self-join for this purpose:

```
SELECT W1.column2, W2.column2 
   FROM words W1 
        JOIN words W2 ON W1.column1 = W2.column1
```

Correct me if I miss something in your question but this 3 lines must be sufficient.

Python looks as irrelevant for your question. It could be solved in pure SQL